# Is it necessary to normalize/standardize data in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

I have features with 18 dimensions after doing feature selection and will be used to train classifier, RNN, HMM, etc.

The features contain stddev, mean and derivative of accelerometer and gyroscope.
These features have different units and normalization/standardization will lose the true meaning of features.

For example, the unit of one feature vector is rotational velocity (degree/sec), the value in that feature is between -120 and 120.
Another is stddev of acceleration of x-axis, the value is mainly between 0 and 2.
If I want to do standardization, all the feature vectors will be centered near 0, with negative/positive values spread around zero. --> Even the stddev will have negative values! It totally loses actual meaning?

Am I on the wrong track? Any information is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This is not suited for SO. anyways you have an anwser [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189652/is-it-a-good-practice-to-always-scale-normalize-data-for-machine-learning)

Answer (score -2):

It is always strongly recomendated to perform feature scaling and normalization as preprocessing step, and it will even benefit gradient descent(the most common learning algorithm),even in your case it would be useful but if you are in doubt you can perform cross validation. For example when using images and neural networks, sometimes after normalization the features(pixels) get negative values, that doesnt make the training data to lose meaning.